# How can you replicate Sand/Perlite?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, texture

Just finished patching two rather large but thin cracks that required taping and 8" on either side of joint compound/feathering. It looks rather smooth and would blend in nicely if it weren't for the fact that the wall has a texture to it.

I believe the name is Sand or Perlite? Although it is a very fine texture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8B8A.jpg

I know that home depot and the like have [additives to paint](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Homax-Sand-Texture-Paint-Additive-8474/202061377) that will help achieve the desired sand look.

However, I am wondering what has been your experience in matching sand textured wallpaper with the rest, and if using an additive such as the one provided in the link above is better than say: using a paint roller to roll on some joint compound?

Or should I even do it at all? In a small repair behind a doorway with the same texture the paint roller was able to recreate some of the 'sandy' appearance and is rather unnoticeable. I am just concerned as the area in question is highly visible.

Comment: That doesn't look like texture at all; looks more like orange peel and spatter, from an airless paint sprayer.

Answer (score -1):

That type of texture is created using specialty spray equipment and requires a bit of skill and experience to master.

I would recommend, for your small repair, that you experiment with readily available spray texture "in a can". There are many types available, practice on cardboard until you can reliably spray it to match your texture.

[image]